# How to add onclick to a html element dynamically using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, onclicklistener

I am able to create a button element and add an onclick event as shown below.

```
elem.onclick=function()
{
alert("qweqweqwe");
}
```

How do I go about using a predefined function instead of defining a function inside of the event? Something like:

```
elem.onclick=func();
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

add an eventlistener to the element which has a defined function to call :

```
elem.addEventListener("click", func, false); //where func is your function name
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener

Answer (score 13):

The best way which i found out for myself is like below.

```
const li = document.createElement('li');
        li.innerText = "client";
        li.id ="key";
        li.className = "client-class";
        li.setAttribute("onclick","valid;");
```

Comment: The only way I managed to get the function to actually run. Setting it with `elem.onclick=...` doesn't seem to work anymore, for me at least

Comment: Best solution I have seen for this issue. This actually adds it as an attribute on the Div like you would if you didnt need to add dynamically

Comment: I like this more than the EventListener because I had a scenario where the code was dynamic, similar to needing to run eval(), and not a fixed function.  Otherwise I'd add a listener.

Answer (score 3):

1)

```
function myfunction(){
alert("hello");
}

elem.onclick=myfunction();
```

or

2)

```
var myfunction=function(){
alert("hello");
}
elem.onclick=myfunction;
//or
elem.onclick=myfunction.call();
```

Answer (score 2):

In my case this worked..,

```
    const elementname = document.getElementById('elementId');
    elementname.setAttribute("onclick","functionName()");
```

to pass parameters..,

```
    var a = 10;
    var b = 20;                                              
    const elementname = document.getElementById('elementId');
    elementname.setAttribute("onclick",`functionName(${a},${b})`);
```

and to create new element..,

```
    const elementname = document.createElement('span');
    elementname.innerText = "Hii..!";
    elementname.setAttribute("onclick","functionName()");
```

// You can add prameters in it as shown in above examples.

Answer (score 0):

```
var clickHandler = function(){

};

elem.onclick = clickHandler;
```

---

```
function clickHandler(){

};

elem.onclick = clickHandler;
```

---

Basically `functions` are kind of variables in `javascript`

if done as in method 1, its obvious.

but even if you do it as in method 2, it does the same thing, creates a variable with name `clickHandler` and type `function` with value , the function body.

when you do

```
elem.onclick = function(){};
```

you are creating an anonymous function without a name, and assigning it to `onclick` of the element

**Meanwhile** this method of binding handlers to events are kind of deprecated. Most browsers have better methods to do it, solving many common problems like say adding more than one handlers to same event. Once you understand this concept of functions move on and check the w3c model event registrations as opposed to this traditional model. Using the traditional method is well supported and ok, it just happens that you have better engineered options.

Answer (score -1):

Using pure javascript

```
<div id="test">Click me to alert</div>
```

--

```
    document.getElementById("test").onclick=callme;

function callme()
{
    alert("You have clicked me!");
}
```

Demo  [here](http://jsfiddle.net/DdfmZ/1/)

Comment: that's not what he asked for

Answer (score -4):

**HTML:**

```
<button>Button</button>
<div id="buttons">
</div>
```

**JS (I used jQuery):**

```
$('button').click(function(){
    var dyn_button = '<button onclick="javascript:test()">Dynamic button</button>'
    $('div#buttons').append(dyn_button + "<br>");
});


function test()
{
    alert(123);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/IceManSpy/FaXgr/