# Adding addtional content (+=) to an HTML attribute

Tags: javascript, html, ecmascript-6

I have an HTML onclick attribute and I'm trying to dynamically add additional properties to it on keypress without removing the existing property.
In other words....

Say I have

```
<button onclick="doThis(1)">
```

Every time a button is pressed I'd like to add to that so the first time the button is pressed you'd get

```
<button onclick="doThis(1), doThis(2)">
```

third time:

```
<button onclick="doThis(1), doThis(2), doThis(3)">
```

etc.

Is there some way to do

```
document.getElementById("mybtn").onclick += doThis($n{index};
```

or do I just have to build up the string independently?

I can't seem to figure it out without building up a big string to add to a setAttribute.  When I try a variation of the JS code above I crash the browser :(

Thx for taking a look!!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add onclick to a html element dynamically using javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22604401/how-to-add-onclick-to-a-html-element-dynamically-using-javascript)

Comment: It would make a lot more sense to just have a single handler for onclick that take care of the logic. Simply have an array in which you add the function to run with the given argument. Then your handler can simply loop over the array and execute them in the right order.

Comment: @Liam No, it's not the same thing.

Comment: Consider that this might be a typo: `document.getLelemtById("mybtn").onclick += doThis($n{index};`, it should be `getElementById`

Comment: @GillesC Thx! The problem is that the function will grow or shrink dynamically depending on user interaction.  I need the same onclick to handle the same function but may need to call up several times simulatenously.  This use case will come up several times in this project so a "setAttribute" type of solution would work best...if it is possible.

Comment: @Bonatti.  Thx but that was just a typo on here.  The original code is typo free

Comment: I wish people would read the question before down voting and telling me the answer has already been given elsewhere.  It is not the same as "How to add onclick to a html element dynamically using javascript".  If I am not explaining correctly please ask me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, I really don't like this answer, but it does do what you are looking for. I don't like it because it relies on setting event handlers as properties of DOM objects, rather than using the W3C DOM Level 2 Event Model. But, aside from that, here you go...

```js
window.doThisCounter = 1;
var eventList = "";

function doThis(){
      console.log(eventList);
      window.doThisCounter++;
      eventList += "doThis(" + window.doThisCounter + ");";
      btnGo.setAttribute("onclick", eventList);
}


// This will execute once, when page is ready:
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){
  
  var btn = document.getElementById("btnGo");

  (function(counter){
    eventList = "doThis(1);";
    btnGo.setAttribute("onclick", eventList);
  }(window.doThisCounter));
  
});
```

```html
<button id="btnGo">Click Me!</button>
```

Comment: That will no do what the OP is after. Each handler will have the same value for `doThisCounter` which mean when `doThis` run the `counter` argument will be the same for all.

Comment: @GillesC Apparently, you didn't run the code. The argument is incremented with each new event handler registration - - just as the OP showed. There is no closure around `counter`.

Comment: Scott, thank you for the clear answer but I don't think I'm explaining myself correctly.  It would be more like if every time someone clicked "Click Me" a second counter was initiated.  Same functionality, same code, same name, but an independent call to the same function (while the original exists).  Hope that makes sense.

Comment: Yes but only the new numbers are being ran, not the old ones which is not what the OP is after. Which he made clear with `onclick="doThis(1), doThis(2), doThis(3)"` after the third time. As in `1` need to be used again.

Comment: @Fedreg I don't think you are explaining yourself clearly. This code does do this. Let me ask you...on the second click, how many functions should run?

Comment: @ScottMarcus 2.  I see where the possible confusion is.  I'll edit my question.   So 1 function initially, ++ every time button is pressed so on the 5th press I'd have 6 funcions.   This is for a music project.  So originally you'd have one voice creating music.  On subsequent keypresses additional instruments would join in.  Does that make more sense?

Comment: @ScottMarcus I see you edited your answer...Let me dig through that a bit to see if it is what I need.  Thx!

Comment: @ScottMarcus thank you!!  I can use that.  It is fine that it is a dom property in this case.   This will work!  Thanks!