# attr new onclick function not working

Tags: jquery

I am replacing an onclick attr as so....

```
$('#divName').attr('onclick','newFunction()');

function newFunction(){
    alert('New Function Success');
}
```

My current html is

```
<div id="divName" onclick="oldFunction()">
```

and after i insert the new attr , inspecting element shows this

```
<div id="divName" onclick="newFunction()">
```

but when i click , no alert msg is displayed, so new function is not being applied on click event , any ideas why ?

Comment: [`.click(newFunction)`](https://api.jquery.com/click/), possibly after [`.off('click')`](https://api.jquery.com/off/). Attributes are meant for communicating the initial state of the document, not necessarily to keep track of further revisions to it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add onclick to a html element dynamically using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22604401/how-to-add-onclick-to-a-html-element-dynamically-using-javascript)

Answer (score 3):

You should use unobtrusive event handler and use [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on) to attach event handler

```
var $elem = $('#divName');

//Remove previous event handler
$elem.prop('onclick',null);

//Bind new event handler
$elem.on('click', newFunction);
```

```js
function oldFunction() {
  console.log('old funnction.');

  var $elem = $('#divName');

  //Remove previous event handler
  $elem.prop('onclick', null);

  //Bind new event handler
  $elem.on('click', newFunction);

  console.log('New Event handler attached, click again');
}

function newFunction() {
  console.log('New Function Success');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="divName" onclick="oldFunction()">click me</div>
```

Comment: @MShack, See the code snippet, when you want to execute the script?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what the purpose of that codes.
but i try to give you another solution.
Hope will solve your problem.

html:

```
 <div id="divName" onclick="oldFunction()">
```

on script:

```
 $('#divName').addClass('newClass');

 $('.newClass').click(
   function(){
    alert('New Function Success');
   }
 );
```

if you need to change another function you can change your attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Since jQuery provides .click() function, you can user this instead. 
Please try the below solution. 
Remove the onlick and attach click() to div

```
$("#divName").attr("onclick","").click(newFunction);

function newFunction(){
    alert('New Function Success');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I were facing the same issue.
Checked on the console.It showed `onclick="newFunc()"` but when inspected the button it shows `oldFunc()` after click `oldFunc()` invoked.
Simply replaced my code with pure JavaScript i.e used `document.getElementbyId` and used `setAttribute()` for updating onclick.

```
var btn=document.getElementById('myBtn');
btn.setAttribute('onclick',"test()");
```