# How to print table rows data in console

Tags: javascript, html

I've created dynamic table rows using javascript for loop and I want to fire a click event
on row in a way that whenever user clicks on any row it should be visible in console log.

```
<tbody>
<script>
for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++){
document.write("<tr>");
document.write("<td>"+data[i]['col1']+"</td>");
document.write("<td>"+data[i]['col2']+"</td>");
document.write("<td>"+data[i]['col3']+"</td>");
document.write("<td>"+data[i]['col4']+"</td>");
document.write("<td>"+data[i]['col5']+"</td>");
}
</tbody>
</script>
```

I know there are many answers for this but I tried and none helping me and some prints as
undefined.

Here is what I tried:

```
var table = document.getElementById("tableID");
if (table) {
for (var i = 0; i < table.rows.length; i++) {
table.rows[i].onclick = function() {
tableText(this);
};
}
}
```

Comment: What is the content of function `tabletext`?

Comment: I think you should attach an evenlistener:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22604401/how-to-add-onclick-to-a-html-element-dynamically-using-javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your javascript code looks correct to me but I think you're not placing it at correct place.

Try this:

```
<script>
for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++){
    document.write("<tr>");
    document.write("<td>"+data[i]['col1']+"</td>");
    document.write("<td>"+data[i]['col2']+"</td>");
    document.write("<td>"+data[i]['col3']+"</td>");
    document.write("<td>"+data[i]['col4']+"</td>");
    document.write("<td>"+data[i]['col5']+"</td>");
}



function tableText(tableRow) {
  var name = tableRow.childNodes[1].innerHTML;
  var age = tableRow.childNodes[3].innerHTML;
  var obj = {'name': name, 'age': age};
  console.log(obj);
}


let tableData = document.getElementById('tableID').getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0]; 
for (let i = 0; i < tableData.rows.length; i++)
    {
        tableData.rows[i].onclick = function()
        {
            tableClicked(this);
        };
    }                       

function tableClicked(rowData) {
    let msg = rowData.cells[0].innerHTML+'*'+rowData.cells[1].innerHTML+'*'+rowData.cells[2].innerHTML+'*'+rowData.cells[3].innerHTML+'*'+rowData.cells[4].innerHTML;
    console.log(msg,data);
};
</script>
```

Comment: Be careful with the use of `.getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0]`because you don't know that the questioner have declared this tag in his table.

Comment: @Reporter good point, I should have read question carefully!

Comment: @Ran If this worked, it means you used `tbody` tag can you plz updated the question?

Answer (score 0):

Your Javascript code looks correct to me, and assuming `tableText = console.log` printed the correct row for me when I used it on a table.

Although I noticed in your table creation code that you are not closing your table row with `</tr>`.

```
for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++){
  document.write("<tr>");
  document.write("<td>"+data[i]['col1']+"</td>");
  document.write("<td>"+data[i]['col2']+"</td>");
  document.write("<td>"+data[i]['col3']+"</td>");
  document.write("<td>"+data[i]['col4']+"</td>");
  document.write("<td>"+data[i]['col5']+"</td>");
  document.write("</tr>");
}
```